# Laravel 4 : Unable to access Auth instance inside package class

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this class in a workbench package:

```
class SomeClass{

//Constructor
function __construct(){

    $isAuth = Auth::check();   

    }
```

But it gives me following error:

```
Class 'vendor\pachage\Auth' not found
```

Is this a namespace issue? I am using the following namespace:

```
namespace vendor\pachage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Fully qualified name, add a backslash:

`\Auth::check()`;

It all described as [Namepace resolution.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)